# TerminateProcess() returns EINVAL

Tags: windows, go, winapi

I'm trying to debug a problem and I don't understand it.

```
func BackgroundProcess(lpCommandLine string) (error) {
    var lpProcessAttrs windows.SecurityAttributes
    var lpThreadAttrs windows.SecurityAttributes
    var lpProcInfo windows.ProcessInformation
    var lpStartup windows.StartupInformation

    // convert to null terminated
    lpCli, err := StringToLpStr(lpCommandLine)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if ok := CreateProcess(nil, lpCli, &lpProcessAttrs, &lpThreadAttrs, true, 0, nil, nil, &lpStartup, &lpProcInfo); !ok {
        return GetLastError()
    }
    // DeleteProcessAccessRight is just a const for 1
    childProcessHandle = OpenProcess(DeleteProcessAccessRight, false, lpProcInfo.dwProcess)
    if ok := TerminateProcess(childProcessHandle, 0); !ok {
        return GetLastError()
    }
}
```

If I call this with `BackgroundProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")` I get the error `EINVAL`, which is `invalid argument`, on `TerminateProcess`. Looking at the MSDN docs for TerminateProcess, you need to first open access to the process with a PROCESS_TERMINATE access right. I am opening the process with that access right, so it should just work. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's the final `GetLastError` that gives said result?

Comment: Why are you trying to kill the process immediately after creating it?

Comment: for what you call `OpenProcess` when you already have process handle ? then you not check result of `OpenProcess` - are it fail.

Comment: and (i not know go) are error returned from call `TerminateProcess` or from call `OpenProcess` ? i guess second. you got `STATUS_INVALID_CID` from `OpenProcess` which is mapped to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. the `TerminateProcess` you even not call

Comment: `CreateProcess()` returns a process handle that has all access rights applied to it, there is no need to call `OpenProcess()` at all.

Comment: `EINVAL`? Please don't mix up C/POSIX error codes with Windows API calls. It makes no sense at all to talk about `EINVAL` in this context.

Comment: @eryksun Microsoft implements a lot of POSIX-compliant APIs in their CRT. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=vs-2017. `EINVAL` is a valid error in the Windows API.

Comment: `EINVAL` is not a Windows API code and has nothing at all to do with `TerminateProcess`. The Windows API has a well-known set of [system error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes), which in a larger context are mapped as [`HRESULT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198) values with `FACILITY_WIN32` (7), e.g. 0x80070016 (`ERROR_BAD_COMMAND`, 22). This does not include POSIX error codes such as `EINVAL` (22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out this specific problem. I was testing with `C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe`, which is a Universal Windows App, which has a runtime broker. As soon as I started testing with `C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe`, it started working. OnceI figure out how to handle runtime brokers, I'll update this answer.